# Get docker logs into filebeat without root

Tags: docker, logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm trying to gather logs from all my running docker containers and send them into the ELK stack. I'd like to use filebeat to do this so I'm following a similar approach to what is described in https://logz.io/blog/docker-logging/.

My filebeat.yml

```
filebeat:
  inputs:
  - paths:
    - /var/jenkins_home/jobs/*/branches/*/builds/*/log
    document_type: jenkinslog
  - type: docker
    containers.ids: '*'
    document_type: docker     
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.5.2
COPY filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER root
RUN chown root:filebeat /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

My command to run this image:

```
docker run --rm --name filebeat_container --volumes-from jenkins_container:ro -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker --network=ttydinternproject_default filebeatimage
```

I'm mounting the /var/lib/docker folder as a volume and have to be root to access it as according to this https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6822#issuecomment-169826764
"/var/lib/docker is for the docker daemon and no one else.".

There must be a better way to get docker container logs into filebeat than to leave the filebeat container running root to access folders to apparently shouldn't even be accessed. Do I need to switch from the default docker logging driver to one of the other ones supported?

Comment: you can change docker log driver to fluent-driver. and it can makes send logs to configured destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconfigure your Jenkins container to publish its log files to a host directory (use `docker run -v` to provide some host directory for the `/var/jenkins_home/jobs` tree; this is probably a good idea regardless since you don't want to lose all of your job history if you ever need to update the underlying Jenkins code).  You can then either use `docker run -v` to inject that same directory into the Filebeat container, or just run Filebeat directly on the host (if its principal job is reading host-system files...).

If you have the option and are in a more productiony setup, switching log drivers to point at your logstash is also a good idea, but that will only collect the main process's stdout and stderr (instead of having to run `docker logs` that data will show up on your central log server).  That won't collect the per-Jenkins-job log files, though.

My experience agrees with the Vagrant bug you quote: never look inside `/var/lib/docker`, and especially don't try to mount Docker's internal state into a Docker container.  (You *probably* won't get a kernel panic.)

Comment: Using the logstash-gelf-input plugin and it's working like a charm